# How to get map values by index when inside each loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, cypress

I try to write tests in a clean way.
I iterate through the rows (each of which shows info about attached file) of the table on the page and verify if each attached file has correct size:

```
   it('attaches many documents', () => {
     const fileSizes = ['17.19 KB', '12.06 KB', '67.75 KB']
     cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile([excelFilePath, docxFilePath, pdfFilePath])

   
     cy.get('div.table-body>.table-row').each(($el, index) => {
       expect($el.find('.col-upload-size')).to.contain.text(fileSizes[index])
     })
        
   })
```

But earlier in the code I have this map defined:

```
const fileSizesMap = new Map([
    ["excelFileSize", "17.19 KB"],
    ["docxFileSize", "12.06 KB"],
    ["pdfFileSize", "67.75 KB"]
]);
```

Can I somehow get rid of `fileSizes` list inside of the test and make use of `fileSizesMap` instead?

Comment: are the keys of the map rendered inside each row? If yes, get the key from each row,  use the map to get the fileSize based on key and write the assertions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to return an iterable for values and do your assertions:

```
const fileSizesMap = new Map([
    ["excelFileSize", "17.19 KB"],
    ["docxFileSize", "12.06 KB"],
    ["pdfFileSize", "67.75 KB"]
]);

it('attaches many documents', () => {
    cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile([excelFilePath, docxFilePath, pdfFilePath])
    for (const value of fileSizesMap.values()) {
        cy.get('div.table-body>.table-row').then(() => {
            expect($el.find('.col-upload-size')).to.contain.text(value)
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: I changed the approach and decided to resign from the `fileSizesMap` for the sake of array with json objects which fits my needs. Anyways your response works so I am accepting it as the solution to the problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to replace `fileSizes` with the values from your `fileSizesMap`:

```js
const fileSizes = Array.from(fileSizesMap.values())
```

Comment: That is a good idea. But can I actually get rid of `fileSizes` list inside of the test and make use of `fileSizesMap` instead?

Comment: Yes, you can replace `fileSizes[index]` with something like `fileSizesMap.get(key)`, but you'd need some way to define `key`. Judging by your code maybe you don't need a map, but just a regular array with objects that have a `path`, `name` and `size` field.

Comment: You are right. I am quite new to JavaScript/Typescript and I didn't see it from my perspective. I created `const files` as you described and I can use it's properties throughout the tests which fulfils my needs. Thank you very much!